# Pasting selected columns into new column with separator in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ["a","b"],
            'col2'  : ["ab","XX"], 'col3' : ["w","e"], 'col4':["foo","bar"]})
```

Which looks like this:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a   ab    w  foo
1    b   XX    e  bar
```

What I want to do is to combine `col2, 3, 4` into a new column called `ID`

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 ID
0    a   ab    w  foo ab.w.foo
1    b   XX    e  bar XX.e.bar
```

How can I achieve that?

I tried this but failed:

```
df["ID"] = df.apply(lambda x: '.'.join(["col2","col3","col4"]),axis=1)

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
  col1 col2 col3 col4              ID
0    a   ab    w  foo  col2.col3.col4
1    b   XX    e  bar  col2.col3.col4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `x[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']]`

```
In [54]: df.apply(lambda x: '.'.join(x[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']]),axis=1)
Out[54]:
0    ab.w.foo
1    XX.e.bar
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

A small typo in your code, you should use the `x` that is being passed into the lambda function to access those values :

```
In [29]: df["ID"] = df.apply(lambda x: '.'.join([x['col2'],x['col3'],x['col4']]),axis=1)

In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
  col1 col2 col3 col4        ID
0    a   ab    w  foo  ab.w.foo
1    b   XX    e  bar  XX.e.bar
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit simpler which runs faster:

```
df['id'] = df.col2 + '.' + df.col3 + '.' + df.col4
```

Illustrative timing with 10000 rows:

```
>>> t1 = timeit.timeit("df['id'] = df.col2 + '.' + df.col3 +'.' + df.col4", "from __main__ import pd,df", number=100)
```

Yields `0.00221121072769s per loop`

```
>>> t2 = timeit.timeit("df.apply(lambda x: '.'.join(x[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']]), axis=1)","from __main__ import pd,df", number=100)
```

Yields `3.32903954983s per loop`